# Maintaining the collection in a List/ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, prism

i have been successfully adding an item to list in a MVVM, and now my problem is maintaining the list in the view model. Every time i navigate to a page or go back to a page and return to that listview, the list resets. how will i able to achieve that? i am currently using the prism to build the MVVM.

The ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<CartData> _cartData;

public ObservableCollection<CartData> CartData
        {

         get {
             return _cartData;
             }
        set {

                SetProperty(ref _cartData, value);
           }
        }




        private DelegateCommand _addItemCommand;
        public ICommand AddItemCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_addItemCommand == null)
                {
                    _addItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddToCart);
                }
                return _addItemCommand;
            }
        }

        public void AddToCart() {

            CartData.Add(new CartData { Cakename = "Black Forest", Cakeprice = 104 });
                   }
```

View:

```
 .....

 <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:CartingDataSource/>
    </Page.DataContext>
   ....
<ListView
            x:Name="itemListView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
            TabIndex="1"
            Margin="-10,130,0,264"
            Padding="120,0,0,60"

            ItemsSource="{Binding cartData}"
            IsSwipeEnabled="False" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemClick="itemListView_ItemClick" SelectionChanged="itemListView_SelectionChanged_1" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="6">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="60" Height="60">
                            <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" Source="Assets/wewewew.jpg"/>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cakename}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" MaxHeight="40"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cakeprice}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: I believe this issue is the exact same as this other one you also posted: [Keep the collections in the list in MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189517/keep-the-collections-in-the-list-in-mvvm). As I commented you on that discussion, it seems that you would be registering the View as _**Non-Singleton**_ instance. Therefore, the container would not mantain a reference of the View and create a new one each time you navigate into it. However, if you do register the View as Singleton, it would be helpful if you could show how are you registering the types, and Navigating to them. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Here if your ViewModel is `CartingDataSource` in that case it is being instatiated on every page load. Now if that is the case, then you are creating a new instance of your collection in your constructor as below:

```
public CartingDataSource() {


        CartData = new ObservableCollection<CartData>();

      }
```

As a result of which it re-initializes your collection.

You need to remove the initialization from your constructor and do something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<CartData> _cartData;

public ObservableCollection<CartData> cartData
    {

     get {
            if(_cartData == null)
            {
                 _cartData = new ObservableCollection<CartData>();
            } 
         return _cartData;
         }
    set {

            _cartData = value;
       }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but that doesnt work, i am using the same mvvm for the 2 pages.

Comment: Is CartingDataSource your ViewModel?

Comment: Then if you debug your code, you will find that everytime your View, that is bound to your CartingDataSource class is rendered, at that time your ViewModel constructor will be called. Now because you have re-initialized your collection in the constructor, it will always retrun a new collection everytime your View is loaded. You will definately need to remove the that from your constructor.

Comment: what does that i need to remove? this one? `CartData = new ObservableCollection<CartData>();` but i have already removed that and applied your answer but no to avail :(

Comment: I have updated the answer. I believe you are using custom `SetProperty` method to set `_cartData`. Can you try this one? If your set works properly and the collection is properly updated, then you will have to look for re-initialization of your collection throughout the code.

Comment: that does'nt work also, thanks for your time! maybe prism does not allow that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48933/discussion-between-hack-luminence-and-mustafa)