# Like statement equivalent in Windows Azure table

Tags: c#, xaml, azure, microsoft-metro

im wondering if there is a like statement in azure table storage. im using this this statement to get a specific data:

`myTable.Where(userinfo => userinfo.Username == txtUsername.Text.ToLower());`

is there any way to make it like this:

```
select * from tblUsers where username like 'D%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myTable.Where(userinfo => userinfo.Username.StartsWith("D");
```

Comment: i have question to this statement, what if the text is "Deb"? does it still search for a username that consists of "Deb"?

Comment: it will search for one that starts with "Deb". if you want "%Deb%" then change it to `.Contains`

Answer (score 1):

Though not recommended but you could do range queries. So your code would be something like:

```
myTable.Where(userinfo => (userinfo.Username >= 'D' && userinfo.Username < 'E'));//Not tested code
```

The statement above will return you all users whose username starts with letter `D`. However you would need to keep 2 things in mind:

1. This would result in full table scan. This may not be a big issue if the number of records are in the table are small but would be an issue if your table is big.
2. Since this query is doing full table scan, be prepared to get continuation tokens i.e. the query won't return any result but gives you a continuation token which you would need to use to send next request to table service. You may find this link useful in understanding continuation tokens: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135718.aspx.

Comment: offtopic: do you think you can help me regarding to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163110/maintaining-the-collection-in-a-list-observablecollection ? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Natively Azure Table only support few operators:

```
Equal               eq
GreaterThan         gt
GreaterThanOrEqual  ge
LessThan            lt
LessThanOrEqual     le
NotEqual            ne
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894031.aspx

Comment: can you please give me an example on how im going to use that?